# Getting an index of a map object inside a LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, linkedhashmap

can you please help me, retrieve the index of a map object which is added to a LinkedList.

```
int p;
List<Map> list=new LinkedList<Map>();
Map<Integer, Integer> map=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for(int i=2;i<=n;i=i+2){
    if(i==n && i%2!=0){
       map.put(i, i+1);
       list.add(map);
    }else{
        map.put(i,0);
        list.add(map);
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the index of map object with  key 'p'

I tried below, but I might be wrong in understanding the method. please help

list.indexOf(map.get(p));

Comment: There is only one map in your code, which you add multiple times to your list. There seem to be even more problems in understanding, e.g. why do your think it's relevant that the list is a `LinkedList`. Further `List<Map>` is referring to the raw type `Map`. It should be `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>`. Mind that you don't need to repeat the type parameters in the `new` expression, but can simply use `<>`. And the condition in your `if` statement will never be fulfilled.

Comment: Also, if your list contains maps, you should pass a map as argument to indexOf(). Not an Integer. A list of maps will never contain an Integer, because a Map will never be equal to an Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the list and check which map has this key:

```
int p = /* key to find */
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if (list.get(i).containsKey(p)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```